# Unit-Testing: Where to start writing my First Tests

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, unit-testing, nunit

My question is, where is an easy place in the codebase to begin writing unit testing for so I can get my feet wet and develop some basic skills?

The details: 
I am a recently hired junior dev and I have been tasked with adding unit testing to my company's projects. I've installed NUnit, watched tutorials, done the basic samples, and am reading through the official docs. I can see the value of automated unit testing, plus think it's a good way to get familiar with my company's source code.

We have 2 online platforms, a "brochure" site to attract clients and our "database" site. both written in Written in Javascript, jQuery, C#, .NET, connecting to MSSQL via Entity framework. 
The "brochure" site doesn't have to much user functionality built in. They click links to get to pages of information. And there is a contact request form where they submit basic info so we can contact them. Very simple website. 
The "database" is more complex. Registered users can grab any number of combination of data from different databases, there are access rights involved with various levels of registration. Lots of filtering based on users selections.

There aren't currently any tests written for either but they are both in production. Where would be a good place to begin?
I think I should begin on the simple "brochure" site to learn on, but I do see the testing as being more important in the long-term for the "database" site.

Should I try and test controllers, ajax get/post functions, views?
I think what I'm hoping for is someone to say "these 1,2,3 are simple tests to write, start there" If I'm wrong on this thinking please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the applications currently have no unit tests then it's likely that they aren't immediately "testable." In other words, they may not be built out of smaller classes and methods that can be unit tested. The two go hand-in-hand. People who write unit tests try to write testable code.

Chances are that you may need to refactor a little bit in order to be able to write unit tests. One approach is to look for "low hanging fruit" - areas where that refactoring is easier.

For example, are there large blocks of duplicate code? You could write a class that provides some of that functionality and replace those methods with references to that class. Now you can unit test that class.

Or, does a class have a ton of private methods that all do things seemingly unrelated to the class's primary purpose? There's no way to unit test those private methods, but you could break them out into their own classes.

For the longest time I thought that refactoring meant redesigning the code to use dependency injection or rewriting classes to depend on abstractions, and that made it seem overwhelming. I recently read something that changed my outlook on that. [Here it is](http://www.daedtech.com/intro-to-unit-testing-5-invading-legacy-code-in-the-name-of-testability/). The article is titled "Invading Legacy Code in the Name of Testability."

The gist is this (or at least what I remember): Suppose we have a class that calls a bunch of private methods, and that class is untestable. We could put that method in its own class, refactor it to make it testable, and then write unit test for it.

Then, in our original class, we change

```
DoSomethingInAPrivateMethod();
```

to

```
var doesSomething = new DoesSomething();
doesSomething.DoSomething();
```

Now we can write unit tests for our `DoesSomething` class.

Normally we might try to avoid creating new classes like that. We're still not applying the principles of OOP. But in this case, what we've done is taken a small piece of code that couldn't be tested and made it testable. It's not ideal. It's not the way we'd like to write our code. But it's *better than it was*. At least now *something* has unit tests.

You might get to move 20 lines of code out of one class and put it in another. At least now that original class is a tiny bit more manageable. Maybe after doing that the original class will get to the point where you can unit test it, too.

Comment: thank you. i think you're right, i might have to do some refactoring to be able to test this code. now to try and figure out how to do that....

Comment: That article really made me think differently about working with legacy code. For better or worse the world is full of messy code, so being able to work with it is a valuable skill. Cleaning it up could be rewarding just like building something new.

Comment: Thanks Scott. I'm still trying to get used to my current projects architecture. I think they are still writing "legacy" code. All the data is passed to the views using viewbags instead of viewmodels ( I was told I'll be taught how to code "old school" for suggesting viewmodels ), all of our javascript is in one file, and there are no services, business logic is being done in the controllers....

Answer (score 0):

First of all: There are different type of tests to think about.
Unit tests in general are used to test small units (functions for example).
So writing tests for every complexer function (no need to test getters and setters or something similar) in a Class/Module could be a good point to start. Calls to a database or other external services (e.g. API) should be mocked.

You can create a folder/sub project "tests" in the root folder of your project. The structure of this test folder should be like your code project sources to make it easy to find the test class/files for a specific class in the code project.

Later you can (and should) think about Integration tests. This is were you can connect to your database or other external service.

Comment: okay, so I've got some code sections that are public class controllers. used for getting and creating website menus and "blogs" of little information. So I think I will start trying to write a few tests off of those functions. If I can get a few of those to work then I'll try mocking some database calls. Sound like an okay plan to you? and yes I have the test project added to the solution as recommended. Thank you for responding btw!